# Vue: Отслеживать изменение переменной внутри дочернего компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js, передача-параметров

*Нужен ответ для vue2 и vue3*

Есть страница `Inputs`, в ней компонент `InputSelect`. Внутри компонента InputSelect добавлен библиотечный компонент `Multiselect`. Из последнего с помощью v-model я получаю `selectedValue`*(его выбранное значение)* и могу работать с ним в InputSelect. А выше передать не могу.

Как мне получить значение `selectedValue` в `Inputs`?

*Я знаю, что это "есть" в официальной документации и много где ещё. Но касательно vue, обычно я нахожу 4 варианта решения проблемы и все они либо не работают вообще, либо относятся к другой версии vue. Помогите пожалуйста! Может где есть более понятная документация по vue?*

*Содержимое файлов очищенное от стороннего кода:*

**Inputs**

```
<template>
  <InputSelect
    v-model="selectedValue"
    :options="testOptions"
  />
  <div class="thisValueDoesntWork">{{ selectedValue }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import InputSelect from '../../components/InputSelect';

export default {
  name: 'PageInputs',
  components: { InputSelect },
  data: function() {
    const testOptions = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];

    return {
      testOptions,
      selectedValue: '',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**InputSelect**

```
<template>
  <div class="inputCont">
    <div class="inputWrapper">
      <Multiselect
        v-model="selectedValue"
        :options="options"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thisValueWorked">{{ selectedValue }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

export default {
  name: 'InputSelect',
  components: { Multiselect },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {}
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedValue: '',
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через стандартную передачу в `emit` (в целом, всё по документации: отлавливаете изменение или по `@input`, или по `@select`, в методе вызываете `this.$emit('changed', this.value)`, а в родительском уже по @changed вызываете метод для изменения; нет смысла полный пример кода приводить).

Более продвинутый и правильный вариант – передавать данные через модель. Реализация для Vue 2 (примерно также и на третьей будет).

Дочерний компонент:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <multiselect
      :id="id"
      v-model="model"
      :track-by="trackBy"
      :label="label"
      :options="options"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :multiple="multiple"
    ></multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SelectField',
  model: {
    prop: 'value',
    event: 'input',
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    trackBy: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'id',
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'title',
    },
    multiple: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
    value: {
      type: [Number, Array],
      required: false,
      default: () => null,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.options.filter((el) =>
          Array.isArray(this.value)
            ? this.value.includes(el.id)
            : el.id === this.value
        )
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit(
          'input',
          Array.isArray(val) ? val.map(({ id }) => id) : val.id
        )
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

В родительском компоненте:

```
<SelectField
    id="select"
    v-model="selectedValue"
    :options="optionsList"
/>
```